# Google Places API - saving place_id and violation of terms and conditions

Tags: java, android, google-maps, statistics, google-places-api

I want to build an app which shows places around user using Google Places based on user interests. As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/places/place-id):

> Place IDs are exempt from the caching restrictions stated in Section
>   10.5.d of the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service. You can therefore store place ID values indefinitely.

So, can I save place_id in cloud database and perform any analytics operation over it? For example; if I gather place_ids added in each user's favorite places table and from analytics; I can know which place_id are the most ones added to favorites? or can I show something like 'Trending Places' in app from gathered place_ids in responses?

Will it violate the [terms and conditions](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies)? I read the whole page of terms but couldn't find the answer.

can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: I'm also saving the place_id for my app and what you are doing seems fine to me although I'm not an expert / nor work for google. I know you are looking for an answer from a credible source and that won't be me but I think the terms and conditions are there so that they can prevent developers from downloading their entire place database & starting up your very own google maps app in competition with google. U are not doing that and u should be free to do what u want to do with the stored place_id including running your own analytics on it.

Comment: Sure no problem. I didnt write it as an answer because I know u want a more credible source so thats why I made a comment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can 100% store the `place_id` indefinitely and reuse it.
See [Referencing a Place with a Place ID](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#placeid).

Please note one thing that

> A single place ID refers to only one place, but a place can have
>   multiple place IDs

Comment: Please also note that place_ids may change

Answer (score 2):

These terms and conditions are kind of self explanatory. Except your requirement which will be clarified after the below link is read carefully. 
As per your requirement , inorder to prevent calling services next time with same query which user had done with an intention of saving network calls **is acceptable**.

**No caching or storage**:
 You will not pre-fetch, cache, index, or store any Content to be used outside the Service, *except that you may store limited amounts of Content solely for the purpose of improving the performance of your Maps API Implementation due to network latency* (and not for the purpose of preventing Google from accurately tracking usage), and only if such storage
1) is temporary (and in no event more than 30 calendar days)
2) is secure
 3) 
does not manipulate or aggregate any part of the Content or Service
 4) and
does not modify attribution in any way. 
Go through this [Section 10.5 Intellectual Property Restrictions. Subsection (B)](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_5)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to contact Google to get a 100% answer.

That being said, from my experience it looks like the clause you included is intended exactly for the kind of thing you want to do.

Again, I want to reiterate that contacting Google directly is something you should do if you still have concerns.

Answer (score 0):

**You can store place ID values indefinitely.**

*Just What part of*

> You can therefore store place ID Values indefinitely.

Don't you understand?

[Indefinitely](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/indefinitely) requires a server.